# disable days in datepicker with mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mobile, datepicker

```
I have been battling with this jquery mobile datepicker for 2 days now!!
```

here is my code, i am retrieving dates with a boolean set to 1, (disabled days), i cannot get datepicker to disable them!! please help..
I am trying to return an array with json to the datepicker from my mysql query

`booked_dates.php` contents:

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
mysql_select_db("eyecandysf");
$booked_date = mysql_query("SELECT date, FROM date_time WHERE booking_status !=0  ");

 while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($booked_date)){

    $dates[] =  $result['date'];
}
echo json_encode($dates);


?>
```

`main.php` contents:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"       href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mobile-bydesign.com/mmc/mobile/3.0.4/themes/eyecandysf22.css" />

<link href="http://mobile-bydesign.com/mmc/mobile/3.0.4/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker_mobile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.getJSON('booked_dates.php', function(data) {
     var bookedDays = data;
    });

  function isAvailable(date){
   var dateAsString = date.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1).toString() + "-" + date.getDate();
   var result = $.inArray( dateAsString, bookedDays ) ==-1 ? [true] : [false];
    return result
    }

    $('#date').datepicker({minDate: 0, maxDate: "+2M", beforeShowDay: isAvailable});

   </script>
<style>
 .ui-select .ui-btn select{
   font-size: 50px;
   }

</style>

</head>


<body>

<form data-ajax="false" id="date" action="time.php" method="post">

<div id="dateDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">    
    <label for="mydate" class="ui-hidden-accessible">date </label>
    <input  name="date" type="date" id="date" data-theme="b" data-role="datebox" value="" placeholder="date"
      data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "afterToday": true,"blackDays": [1], "maxDays": 65}'/>
        </div>
  <input type="submit" value="select time" name="submit" />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Edited to separate code of booked_dates.php and the main file (no idea how it is called in reality, so i called it main.php for the sake of example)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `bookedDays` variable is defined only inside ajax callback (it is a local variable).
And it is even undefined in global scope completely.

So:

```
var bookedDays = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON('booked_dates.php', function(data) {
     bookedDays = data;
     });
});
```

This will both ensure you're working with a global variable, and prevent errors accessing it before the ajax call finished.

EDIT:
Additionally, to avoid problems with date formatting, use `ISO` date on javascript side as well:

```
var dateAsString = date.toISOString().substring(0,10);
```

Comment: Thanks! though that still hasn't fixed it..:(

Comment: What does happen in reality? errors? or it simply does not disable the dates?

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't disable the date... in my testing database I have 07/14 set to 1, so that it should be disabled... but nothing happens...

Comment: aha... theres another catch here, i think - when you request day/month from a javascript `Date` object, you get an integer, **without leading zero** - but dates from mysql come in `ISO` format, which includes leading zero. So, in case the integer you got is less than 10, you should add '0' yourself for comparison to work

Comment: yeah i have thought of that, i tried to change the mysql date format after the SELECT  but it didn't work either..... i seemed to have tried everything!!

Comment: what is the right way to change the returned date format before JSon encode??

Comment: instead of changing date format in mysql, i'd use `.toISOString().substring(0,10)` on a date object you got in javascript

Comment: thanks again...but:( this is brutal!! not this discussion!! the code!!:)

Comment: Weird. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/poncha/R83eE/ The only difference is that the list of dates is static in this case...

Comment: @AndrewLinton oh wait... you have `id="date"` more than once. Change the id on the form to something else.

Comment: thanks so much for the help so far..... it still doesn't work.... here is the actual link ... http://clubfife.com/fifeshop/time.html

Comment: Maybe the problem is that http://clubfife.com/fifeshop/booked_dates.php returns "0" ?

Comment: it shouldn't do that..:)the date 2012-07-14 is set to 1 in the "booking_status" field in the db....

Comment: also because of that, if you select 07/14 the form will not submit as there is no available times on that day.... however i need to disable the day on datepicker so i don't get an ajax spinning wheel for ever...

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't. but it does... ;) so check the database code)

Comment: It isn't that, It is a conflict with datepicker mobile.... it works fine without the mobile script.. just doesn't work with it.....